# PHP code not executing in cron job

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I've a php script which will get all network card mac address and store first one in a text file.
Here is the code which I used to get MAC of system:

```
<?php
$mycom = shell_exec("ifconfig | grep HWaddr");
$findVal = "HWaddr";
$mac_arry = array();

while (strpos($mycom, $findVal) > 0) {
    $start_pos = strpos($mycom, $findVal);
    $mac=substr($mycom,($start_pos+7),17);
    $mac_arry[] = $mac;
    $mycom = substr($mycom, ($start_pos+10));
}

$fileHandle = fopen("/tmp/mac.txt", "a+");
fwrite($fileHandle, $mac_arry[0]);
fclose($fileHandle);
?>
```

If I execute this file directly in browser or through terminal, it works perfectly. But when I add this to cron for every minute, it doesn't work. Here is my cronjob:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/test.php
```

Comment: does the user that executes the cron have the permissions to read/write to the /tmp directory?

Comment: ... or execute `ifconfig` for that matter.

Comment: I'm adding cron as root user and I think root user has the permission

Comment: The cron job executes in an environment that is very different than the one you get in a terminal. The content of the `$PATH` variable is shorter and it's possible that `/sbin` (where `ifconfig` usually stays) is not included. That makes the `shell_exec()` call fail and the rest of the script doesn't matter. Use `which ifconfig` (in a terminal) to find out where `ifconfig` resides on your system and invoke it using its absolute path in `shell_exec()`. The same for `grep` (it probably can be found even without full path because it usually stays in `/bin`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @axiac . You saved my day. It solved my problem. kindly post and answer of all this

Answer (score 0):

by [axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac)

The cron job executes in an environment that is very different than the one you get in a terminal. The content of the `$PATH` variable is shorter and it's possible that `/sbin` (where `ifconfig` usually stays) is not included. That makes the `shell_exec()` call fail and the rest of the script doesn't matter. Use which `ifconfig` (in a terminal) to find out where `ifconfig` resides on your system and invoke it using its absolute path in `shell_exec()`. The same for grep (it probably can be found even without full path because it usually stays in `/bin`.)